# Unlink drive account from android app using google api

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client

I've been able to authorize a google account in my app using

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
      .addApi(Drive.API)
      .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
      .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

then

```
connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
```

that opens a dialog asking user to choose which account they want to authorize.

I'd like to allow users to disconnect or to change linked account.

I guess that google play libraries store information inside my app because when I delete application data, I'm able to ask the user to connect again.

So I would like to know how to unlink a google account from my app.

Comment: i have smae problem , did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should create your Api client with Plus API ;

```
    mApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```

and then you can sign out as like ;

```
Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mApi);
mApi.disconnect();
```

Your app should be successfully unlink from googledrive account.